# Getting the phase of a complex number

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am using the following code - but not getting the phase back in the original
form (3.366):

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cmath

Magn = 0.786236
Phase = 3.366   
cohs = Magn * math.cos(Phase) +  1j*Magn*math.sin(Phase)

Magn_value = np.absolute(cohs)
Phase_value = np.angle(cohs)

print(alpha_value)
print(phase_value)
```

The Magnitude is returned correctly, the phase is, however, returned as -2.9..
Why is that, and how can the original phase value be retrieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the `angle` method: you get the phase expressed in a given range, -π to +π.  If you want it in the more positive range 0 to 2π, simply add 2π to any negative value.

Comment: I just figured that...but I think it is adding 2pi to *any* value (so that also the upper bound, pi, gets shifted to 2pi)

Comment: No, if you add to a positive value, you get a result *greater* than 2π

Comment: Thanks very helpful, my Magn values are between 0 and 1 - what range does python return?

Comment: (1) How do the `Magn` values affect the phase discussion?  (2) Why are you asking *me*?  You have the ultimate authority in front of you: run some tests and see.  Even better, look in the documentation.